# Understanding the choice function

Tags: functions

Let $X = \{A_1, A_2, A_3,\ldots, A_k\}$ where $A_i$ is a non-empty set. Then for every $A_i, f(A_i) \in A_i$. Is that the right definition?

Example: Let $B_1 = \{1, 2\}$  and  $Y = \{B_1\}$. Consider $f(x) = 2x$. Then $f(B_1) = \{2, 4\}$. Does it mean $\{2, 4\} \in \{1, 2\}$?

Comment: I think i) Notice that $X$ needn't be finite. If $X$ is finite, we can always make one choice function without axiom of choice. ii) Pardon, but I don't know why $f(x)=2x$ here is an example for you...and it is certainly not true that $\{2,4\} \in \{1,2\}$.

Comment: The set $Y$ does have choice functions, but $f(x)=2x$ is not one of those choice functions.  An example of a choice function for $Y$ would be $f(B_{1}) = 1$.

Comment: ".. where $A_i$ is a non-empty *set*". This is the key concept : the function $f$ is a *choice* function because it picks up an element of $A_i$ for every $A_i$; thus, there must be elements into $A_i$ ($A_i$ is a non-empty set).

Comment: @ Doug Chatham, $f(B_1) = 1$, but what's $1$? Is $1$ a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, $f$ is not a choice function. A valid choice function $f:Y \to \bigcup_i B_i$ would be given either by $f(B_1) = 1$ or $f(B_1) = 2$. In that case we *would* have $f(B_1) \in B_1$.

For a bigger example, let $Y = \{\Bbb R, \Bbb C, [2, 7), \{1, 2, 3\}\}$. In that case, the function $f$ that always gives the answer $3$ is a valid choice function, but so is the function $g$ given by
$$
g(\Bbb R) = \pi \quad (\in \Bbb R)\\
g(\Bbb C) = \ln(2) + \sqrt2i\quad (\in \Bbb C)\\
g([2, 7)) = e \quad(\in [2, 7))\\
g(\{1, 2, 3\}) = 1 \quad(\in\{1, 2, 3\})
$$
Also note that while in this case, the elements of $Y$ are all subsets of $\Bbb C$, that need not be the case. The elements of $Y$ can be *anything* non-empty. There needn't be any connection between the different $B_i$. And that is what makes the *existence* of choice functions for general infinite sets $Y$ into such a strong statement.

And to adress your question in the comments, in this setting it is common to thing of *everything* as sets. Numbers are sets, functions are sets, relations are sets. The most common construction of the natural numbers, for instance, is to let $0$ be the empty set $\{\}$, then let $n+1$ be given by $n\cup \{n\}$. That means that $1 = \{\{\}\}$ and $2 = \{\{\}, \{\{\}\}\}$

Comment: Isn't $f(B_1)$ image set of $B_1?$

Comment: @person No. $B_1$ is an _element_ of $Y$, not a subset. That means that it is the most basic object to apply $f$ to. $f$ doesn't want the _elements_ of $B_1$ as inputs, because such objects are not elements of $Y$. For instance, $g$ wouldn't know what to do if you tried to calculate $g(5)$, since $5$ is not an element of my $Y$ (even though $5\in \Bbb R$, and $5\in \Bbb C$, that doesn't matter at all). You can find $g(\Bbb R)$, however, and that value is $\pi$.

Comment: @ Arthur, can we also say $g(\mathbb R) = \sqrt2$?

Comment: @person Yes, making that change would still make $g$ a valid choice function. However, something like setting $g([2, 7)) = 10$ would not.

Comment: @ Arthur, since $B_i \in Y$, does that mean $f: Y \to Y$ where $Y = \cup_iB_i$?

Comment: @person No. If $B_i\in Y$, then it's wrong to say $Y\bigcup_iB_i$. You cannot use $Y$ to describe two different sets. You could, however, say something like $f:Y\to Y'$, with $Y'=\bigcup_iB_i$.